# Returning a random subset of a mongo database in express

Tags: arrays, node.js, express

I am learning to code and have been building a trivia game using Mongo, Express, and NodeJS. I've managed to build a game that pulls a random trivia question from a database, takes the user's answer, and checks it to see if it is correct.

Right now the game just continues until the user quits and questions are often repeated. To stop that, I want to pull a random set of 10 questions from the database so I can loop through those.

What I have done so far is create a function that grabs a random question from the database, checks if it is already in an array, and if it isn't, pushes it to the array. But I can't seem to access the questions that are in the array. When I open the route in my browser, I just see an empty array.

I've been staring at this so long and messed around with it so much that I am sure I've gone way off track.

Here's my code:

```
router.get("/q/", function(req,res){       
  res.send(getQuestions());    
});


function getQuestions() {

    var quiz = new Array();

    for(var i = 0; i <  10; i++) {

        Question.findOneRandom(function(err, randomQuestion){

            if(err){
                console.log(err);
            } else {
                if(!containsObject(randomQuestion, quiz)) {
                    console.log("Adding question");
                    quiz.push(randomQuestion);
                } else {
                    console.log("It was a duplicate.");
                }
            }
        });
    }

    return quiz;
}


function containsObject(obj, list){
    for (var i = 0; i < list.length; i++){
        if (list[i].question === obj.question) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are doing an asynchronous work inside a `for` loop, so before your first query even begins the `getQuestions` function returns with the empty array. you should consider learning more about the async nature of nodejs application. here are some good reads:

[Understanding Async Programming in Node.js](https://blog.risingstack.com/node-hero-async-programming-in-node-js/)

[Node.js Async Best Practices & Avoiding the Callback Hell](https://blog.risingstack.com/node-js-async-best-practices-avoiding-callback-hell-node-js-at-scale/)

To answer your question, you could do something like this (by using the [async](http://caolan.github.io/async/) library):

```
    const async = require('async');

    router.get("/q/", function(req,res){       
        // res.send(getQuestions());
        getQuestions(function(err, quiz) {
            if(err) {
                console.log('an error has occured', err);
                return res.send(500);
            }

            res.send(quiz);
        });
    });


    function getQuestions(cb) {
        var quiz = new Array();

        const dummyArray = new Array(10);
        async.eachSeries(dummyArray, function(ignored, done) {
            Question.findOneRandom(function(err, randomQuestion){
                if(err){
                    // console.log(err);
                    done(err);
                } else {
                    if(!containsObject(randomQuestion, quiz)) {
                        // console.log("Adding question");
                        quiz.push(randomQuestion);
                    } else {
                        // console.log("It was a duplicate.");
                    }

                    done();
                }
            });
        }, function(err) {
            if(err) return cb(err);

            cb(null, quiz);
        });

        // for(var i = 0; i <  10; i++) {
        //     Question.findOneRandom(function(err, randomQuestion){
        //         if(err){
        //             console.log(err);
        //         } else {
        //             if(!containsObject(randomQuestion, quiz)) {
        //                 console.log("Adding question");
        //                 quiz.push(randomQuestion);
        //             } else {
        //                 console.log("It was a duplicate.");
        //             }
        //         }
        //     });
        // }

        // return quiz;
    }


    function containsObject(obj, list){
        for (var i = 0; i < list.length; i++){
            if (list[i].question === obj.question) {
                return true;
            }
        }

        return false;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks--this works. I think I need to go read more to understand exactly what is happening, but thanks for your help!